# UBER Api deep link error after sign in

Tags: uber-api

Uber api is not setting the drop location after returning from Register/SignIn .

Uber app is called with the proper params as mentioned here 
https://developer.uber.com/v1/deep-linking/

The intent url is

```
"uber://?client_id=the-client-id&action=setPickup&pickup[latitude]="+latitude+"&pickup[longitude]="+longitude+"&dropoff[latitude]="+dropoff_latitude+"&dropoff[longitude]="+dropoff_longitude
```

Comment: Are you sure the location coordinates are correct?

Comment: Yes i checked it is correct